# Stop jquery cycle at a certain image

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using jquery to cycle through images on page load, like in this example:

http://buildinternet.com/live/cycle-images/

JQUERY

```
$('.diapositivas').cycle({
                fx:     'none',
                speed:   100,
                timeout: 70,
                cleartypeNoBg:true
            }).cycle("pause");


        function runThrough(){
                $('.start-page-img .diapositivas').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
            }

        runThrough();
```

HTML

```
<div class="start-page-img">
    <a href="http://website.com" class="link"></a>
    <ul class="diapositivas">
        <li><img src="image.jpg"/></li>
        <!-- Any other slides -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can stop the cycle when it reaches the last image or a certain image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`autostop` option](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.diapositivas').cycle({
    fx:     'none',
    speed:   100,
    timeout: 70,
    autostop: 1
}).cycle("resume");
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/SLGdE/7/

Answer (score 0):

look if your `cycle()` plugin provides any callbacks and use an appropriate one to check where you are at and if you should call `cycle("pause")`.